# Parse HTML tags in a string in PHP

Tags: php, html

Is there a way I can parse a string with HTML Tags in PHP through some PHP function.

I am unable to write a string as it doesn't show tags here.

So for example this HTML string:-

```
<(bold-tag)>The text<(/bold-tag)>

becomes

**The text**
```

Comment: do you maybe mean "parse" or "interpret" instead of "execute"?

Comment: To clarify, you are looking to remove HTML tags from a given string?

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/763468

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` may be what you're looking for:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Edit: I feel compelled to note the giant warning on the above documentation:

> Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

This is a good point...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str_replace()` by passing it an array of tags and their replacements like so:

```
$tags   = ['<b>','</b>'];
$replace= ['**','**'];
$string = '<b>Text</b>';
$string = str_replace($tags,$replace,$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more generic solution you can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in conjunction with [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). The `strpos` function will give the position of a string and `substr` will allow you to extract the string between the tags.

So for HTML tags you would do something like this:

```
$right = substr($htmlTxt, strpos($htmlTxt, '>') + 1);    // After opening tag
$btwn = substr($right, 0, strpos($right, '</') + 1);     // Before the closing tag
$output = '**' . $btwn . '**';
```

If you are concerned about a failure by something like broken tags then you can make the positions more explicit and add a couple of if statements like this:

```
$endLftTag = '>';
$endLftTagPos = strpos($htmlTxt, strpos($htmlTxt, $endLftTag) + strlen($endLftTag));

if ($endLftTagPos === FALSE) {
  // Not Found, probably return $htmlTxt unchanged
  ...
}

$beginRgtTag = '</';
$beginRgtTagPos = strpos($htmlTxt, strpos($htmlTxt, $beginRgtTag));

if ($endLftTagPos === FALSE) {
  // Opening Tag Not Found
  
  if ($beginRgtTagPos === FALSE) {
    // No Tag Found, return unchanged
    return $htmlTxt;
  } else {
    // Return the portion before the closing tag
    return substr($htmlTxt, 0, $beginRgtTagPos + 1);
  }
} else {
  // Opening Tag was Found

  if ($beginRgtTagPos === FALSE) {
    // Closing Tag Not Found, return everything after $endLftTagPos
    return substr($htmlTxt, $endLftTagPos);
  } else {
    // Both were found, return the string between them
    $strLen = $beginRgtTagPos - $endLftTagPos;
    return substr($htmlTxt, $endLftTagPos, $strLen);
  }
}
```